# Get picture on android

Tags: android

I want to create a simple game for android which is supposed to use a camera. The thing is that I don't really care about the resolution of the picture, what meters to me is speed. I need the picture to be taken the moment a key is pressed. Ideal solution would be to use a frame from camera preview. I need this picture as a table of data for analysis, I don't need a file.

Is this possible to get a single frame form camera/video camera preview?
Or maybe it's easier to get a low resolution picture?
Can you tell me which function would be useful here, and maybe give a short example?
How can I get access to picture data using such a function?

Thanks in advance!
Bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the ZXing barcode scanner's [source code](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java) helpful.